# My Jest test can't find text (notification of no projects available) that should appear when an option (without available data) is selected

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, next.js13

I have a nextjs typescript application using the Jest testing framework with Material UI as the UI framework (as well as some Tremor BI/dashboard components). I am new to testing. My other tests can find and click on my "Select Suppliers" select and select an option ("BlaneyFarm"). My last test tests that doing so should display the message "No projects available for this supplier." but it is not in the document. For it to be displayed the "projects" length must be > 0 and isLoading false. These are assigned in the useEffect hook which calls the api to get the projects data. I am mocking this with a global fetch so perhaps these are not being set? Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the file being tested (no imports included here):

```
interface TrackTargetsProps {
    suppliers: Supplier[];
}
export const TrackTargets = ({ suppliers }: TrackTargetsProps) => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
    const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState({});
    const [selectedSuppliers, setSelectedSuppliers] = useState<Supplier>();
    const [selectedSuppliersId, setSelectedSuppliersId] = useState<
        string | undefined
    >("");
    const { orgId, supplierId, isSupplier, setSupplierId } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [isProjectsLoading, setIsProjectsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Find the supplier object from the suppliers array using the selected ID
        let foundSupplier = null;
        if (selectedSuppliersId != "") {
            foundSupplier = suppliers.find(
                (supplier) => supplier.id === selectedSuppliersId
            );
        }

        // Set the found supplier object to the state
        if (foundSupplier) {
            setSelectedSuppliers(foundSupplier);
            setSupplierId(Number.parseInt(foundSupplier.id));
        }
    }, [selectedSuppliersId, suppliers, setSupplierId]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProjects = async (orgId: number, supplierId: string) => {
            setIsProjectsLoading(true); // Start loading
            const projectResults = await fetch(
                `api/organisation/${orgId}/supplier/${supplierId}/projects`
            );
            const projects = await projectResults.json();
            const projectsFeatureCollection = await projects;
            if (projectsFeatureCollection["features"]?.length > 0) {
                setProjects(projectsFeatureCollection["features"]);
            } else {
                setProjects([]);
            }
            setIsProjectsLoading(false); // Start loading
        };
        if (
            orgId &&
            orgId != NO_ID &&
            selectedSuppliersId &&
            selectedSuppliersId != ""
        ) {
            fetchProjects(orgId, selectedSuppliersId);
        }
    }, [selectedSuppliersId, orgId]);
    return (
        suppliers.length > 0 && (
            <TabPanel>
                <Grid numItemsLg={6} className="gap-6 mt-6">
                    <Col numColSpanLg={3}>
                        <div className="space-y-10">
                            <Card>
                                <div className="flex space-x-14">
                                    <FormControl
                                        fullWidth
                                        sx={{
                                            maxWidth: 300,
                                            mb: 2,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {" "}
                                        {/* Adjust width and max-width as needed */}
                                        <InputLabel id="select-suppliers-label">
                                            Select Suppliers
                                        </InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            labelId="select-suppliers-label"
                                            defaultValue=""
                                            value={selectedSuppliersId}
                                            label="Select Suppliers..."
                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                setSelectedSuppliersId(
                                                    e.target.value
                                                )
                                            }
                                        >
                                            {suppliers.map((item) => (
                                                <MenuItem
                                                    key={item.id}
                                                    value={item.id}
                                                >
                                                    {item.business_name}
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            ))}
                                        </Select>
                                    </FormControl>

                                    <FormControl
                                        fullWidth
                                        sx={{
                                            maxWidth: 300,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {" "}
                                        {/* Adjust width and max-width as needed */}
                                        <InputLabel id="select-project-label">
                                            Select Project
                                        </InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            labelId="select-project-label"
                                            id="selectProject"
                                            value={selectedProject}
                                            label="Select Project..."
                                            onChange={(e) =>
                                                setSelectedProject(
                                                    e.target.value
                                                )
                                            }
                                            defaultValue="10"
                                        >
                                            {projects
                                                .filter(
                                                    (item) => item !== undefined
                                                )
                                                .map((item) => (
                                                    <MenuItem
                                                        key={
                                                            item["properties"][
                                                                "id"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                        value={
                                                            item["properties"][
                                                                "id"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    >
                                                        {
                                                            item["properties"][
                                                                "name"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    </MenuItem>
                                                ))}
                                        </Select>
                                    </FormControl>
                                </div>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Grid>
                <Grid numItemsLg={3} className="mt-6">
                    {!isProjectsLoading &&
                        (projects.length > 0 ? (
                            <Col numColSpanLg={6}>
                                <ProjectAnalysis
                                    selectedProject={
                                        projects.filter(
                                            (item) =>
                                                item["properties"]["id"] ===
                                                selectedProject
                                        )[0]
                                    }
                                />
                            </Col>
                        ) : (
                            // <div className="mt-6">
                            <Col numColSpanLg={3}>
                                <Card>
                                    <p>
                                        No projects available for this supplier.
                                        {isSupplier === false
                                            ? " Please choose another supplier."
                                            : ""}
                                    </p>
                                </Card>
                            </Col>
                            // </div>
                        ))}
                    {/*</div>*/}
                </Grid>
            </TabPanel>
        )
    );
};
```

And this is the Jest testcase (not all the file shown, just the key parts):

````
const mockNoProjectsResponse = {
    features: [],
};


beforeEach(() => {
    // Mock the global fetch function
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
            json: () => Promise.resolve(mockNoProjectsResponse),
        })
    ) as jest.Mock;
});
test("no projects notification is visible for a supplier with no projects", async () => {
        const expectedNoProjects = "No projects available for this supplier.";

        await act(async () => {
            render(<TrackTargets suppliers={mockSuppliersProps} />);
        });

        await user.click(
            await screen.findByRole("combobox", {
                name: /Select Suppliers/i,
            })
        );
        //click on the BlaneyFarm option
        await userEvent.click(
            await screen.findByRole("option", { name: "BlaneyFarm" })
        );

        // Wait for and verify the "No projects available for this supplier." message is displayed

        expect(screen.getByText(expectedNoProjects)).toBeInTheDocument();

        //
    });```
````